# Non-Noetherian Domain Which is Locally Noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, noetherian

> Let $R$ be an integral domain such that the localization, $R_{\mathfrak p}$, at each prime ideal, $\mathfrak p \le R$ is Noetherian. Then is $R$ necessarily Noetherian?

In the case of $R$ not neccesarily being a domain, I know of a couple of examples to show that $R$ need not being Noetherian (e.g. [this](https://yutsumura.com/if-the-localization-is-noetherian-for-all-prime-ideals-is-the-ring-noetherian/) & [this](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=2110.0001)). However, in each example, $R$ is not a domain.

Comment: No, but an example is not easily found. Look (with Google) for an example of almost Dedekind domain which is not Dedekind.

Comment: Loper, K. Allan. "Almost Dedekind domains which are not Dedekind." Multiplicative ideal theory in commutative algebra. Springer, Boston, MA, 2006. 279-292 has a bunch, but as I ran down the list they all seem quite involved. Looks like it takes some work.

Comment: Although I just got to the very end of the list, and it looks like perhaps the group ring of the group $(\mathbb Q,+)$ over the field $\mathbb Q$ might be a concisely described example.

Comment: @rschwieb If I remember well, Example 59 from Hutchins is such an example.

Comment: But I can agree that $K[\mathbb Q]$ could be the simplest example.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks much for the reference! I will take a look.